# Azure Devops sprint taskboard - add a column with collapsible cards for feature or epics

Tags: azure-devops

Azure Devops allows to see PBIs and their associated tasks on sprint taskboard. But what if I want to see the associated Feature or Epic of each PBI?
Is there any way to add a column for Epic or Feature?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but I believe what you're looking for is the Boards section.
Sprint taskboard is useful for detailed viewing of specific tasks (e.g. on a daily stand-up).

Boards taskboard is useful for higher level, basically anything above tasks/bugs. Including epics, features, PBIs, etc.

The trick is to use both of these taskboards in parallel. Sprints for details, Boards for bigger picture.

Comment: My team need is satisfied only if they can see both the epic and PBI in the same place. switching between different boards will loose the big picture.

Comment: Then I would suggest only using the Boards and use PBIs for everything. Avoid Tasks. Without Tasks, you don't really need the ScrumBoard.